# WindowsLookAndFeel unexpected behaviour regarding coloring of buttons

Tags: java, swing, jframe, look-and-feel

Using the WindowsLookAndFeel which is chosen by

```
UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName()
```

since I am working on windows results in unexpected behaviour. The background-color of buttons change. Sometimes they don't in my current project but I am unable to spot the difference.

Buttons with wrong behaviour:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5OUk.png]

Buttons with default LookAndFeel:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMoHv.png]

I will give a working example producing the unexpected behaviour:

```
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class Context {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
        new VocableEditor();
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class VocableEditor extends JFrame implements WindowListener, ActionListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6209345602005762300L;
    private Button b_save, b_discard;
    private GridBagLayout layout;

    public VocableEditor() {

        setTitle("vocableEditorTitle");
        setSize(600, 400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        addWindowListener(this);

        layout = new GridBagLayout();
        setLayout(layout);
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.gridheight = 1;

        b_discard = new Button("discardAndLeave");
        b_discard.addActionListener(this);
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.gridx = 2;
        add(b_discard, c);
        b_save = new Button("saveAndExit");
        b_save.addActionListener(this);
        c.gridx = 3;
        add(b_save, c);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void end(boolean save) {
        System.out.println(save);
        dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == b_save) {
            end(true);
        } else if (e.getSource() == b_discard) {
            end(false);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JButton;

public class Button extends JButton {
    private static final Color BACKGROUND_COLOR = new Color(60, 90, 180);

    public Button(String name) {
        super(name);
        setBackground(BACKGROUND_COLOR);
        setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    }
}
```

Comment: `I will give a working example producing the unexpected behaviour:` - in the future: 1) all the code should be in a single source file. We should be able to copy/paste/compile/test. We don't have the time to manage 3 different files. 2) Only code directly related to the problem should be included. The MouseListener and WindowListener code has nothing to do with the problem. 3) Use a FlowLayout on the panel. Layout of the components is not and issue. The less code posted, the easier for us to read and understand the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After hours of research I found a solution. Oracle says the shown behaviour is wanted even if I can't understand why LAF has to be such intransparent. The solution is adding the following lines to the button's constructor:

```
setContentAreaFilled(false);
setOpaque(true);
```

The first line disables drawing the background and the second one reenables it but misses the part where LAF would change the appearance.